# Should comments containing broken links be flagged?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

The link in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265213/should-i-specify-exact-versions-in-my-gemfile/9265628#comment11679743_9265628) is now broken, so I flagged it as "no longer needed," since the link was outdated. This flag was seemingly marked as both "declined" and "helpful," with the link remaining unchanged.

The comment says:

> @ethan RubyGems has a [doc](http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/Gem/Version.html) explaining it (see section "Preventing Version Catastrophe"). The gist of it is it only allows the last integer in the version number to increase (e.g. '~> 1.0.5' allows updating to version 1.0.9999, but never to 1.1.x). The mechanism is for allowing gems to be updated, but without introducing incompatibilities that may break things (it assumes gems are following the "Rational Versioning" policy that link outlines).

I reflagged per the [declined flags help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/declined-flags) as "something else," and explained that the link is broken and should be removed. This flag was also declined.

Does this behavior seem in line with what's expected from moderator intervention? It seems strange that we would actively keep non-working links on the site. It's worth noting that similar comment flags that I've raised have been addressed (since otherwise on questions or answers I'd make the edit myself).

*Edit*: Clarifying that I am not advocating for deletion of the entire comment. I'm wondering whether it's appropriate to flag a comment with a broken link to indicate to a moderator that it should be edited to only remove the hyperlink.

Comment: That comment did exactly what we want people to do when including a link: it included a *summary* of the linked content, which means that even when the link goes down, the comment is still useful. Why do you think it should be deleted?

Comment: @CodyGray, I don't think the comment should be deleted, rather, I think the comment should be edited to remove the current hyperlink to prevent people from pointlessly clicking out.

Comment: @DavePowers I recommend adding that to your question.

Comment: @DavePower's opening statement is consistent with what he meant: the link was broken so he flagged it as no longer needed.  He was never suggesting that a comment be deleted.

Comment: @geekandglitter FYI, flagging a comment as "no longer needed" is the same as suggesting that the comment be deleted. The flag is applied to the comment, not the link, and all of the non-custom flags are meant to indicate the comment should be deleted. The OP's second step, using a custom flag to indicate the actual result desired, was more in line with the appropriate type of flag to use. Note that it would have been more helpful if the OP had provided a suitable replacement for the link.

Answer (score 2):

That specific comment is useful even if the link doesn't work.

If you found a comment that had no useful content besides a link, and the link was dead, then perhaps deletion would be in order.

Answer (score -1):

Broken links:

1. Are [bad for SEO](https://www.verticalmeasures.com/blog/search-optimization/how-broken-links-hurt-your-seo-and-your-heart/)
2. Cause [site abandonment](https://siteimprove.com/en-us/blog/broken-links-on-135-us-fortune-company-websites/)

All it takes is removing the link; the words surrounding it will remain intact. But in some cases, links can even be fixed. I just repaired one the other day on SO. I did that by googling for the new, updated page, and put that in as the new link.